# Better fit for points with exaggerated deviations

Tags: fitting, interpolation, polynomials

I used the [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) function to get a polynomial that meets my points.

But I noticed that there is a deviation in the final intervals.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
dados16={{10,0.37},{15,0.47},{20,0.54},{25,0.61},{30,0.70},{40,0.80},{50,0.90},{60,1.01},{70,1.10},{80,1.20},{90,1.31},{100,1.42},{110,1.53}};
B16[l_]=InterpolatingPolynomial[dados16,l]//Expand;
Plot[B16[l],{l,0,110},Epilog->{{Red,PointSize[.02],Point[dados16]}}]
```

[image]

What would be the best function to have a better result?

Comment: Can you use `Interpolation` or you do want to have the symbolic formula of the polynomial? Can you use other types of polynomials, say, found with `FindFormula`?

Comment: Yes. Could be through these functions that commented. Could you demonstrate in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically in all variants below we are trying to not let high degree polynomials be used. (Less than degree 12 produced by `InterpolatingPolynomial`.)

### Interpolation

Using `Interpolation` instead of `InterpolatingPolynomial`.

```
Clear[B16]
B16[l_] := 
  Evaluate[Interpolation[dados16, l, InterpolationOrder -> 2] // 
    Expand];
Plot[B16[l], {l, Min[dados16[[All, 1]]], Max[dados16[[All, 1]]]}, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, PointSize[.02], Point[dados16]}}]
```

[image]

### FindFormula

`FindFormula` does not give better result than `InterpolatingPolynomial`. (Obviously "just" a fit.)

```
Clear[FF]
FF[x_] := 
  Evaluate[FindFormula[dados16, x, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]];
Plot[FF[l], {l, Min[dados16[[All, 1]]], Max[dados16[[All, 1]]]}, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, PointSize[.02], Point[dados16]}}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

### Chebyshev polynomials

Better results are obtained with Chebyshev polynomials (`ChebyshevT`).
***(If of interest I can expand on that.)***

[image]

Comment: The goal was to get a function that would give me more accurate values. I tested B16 [32] and I got a satisfactory value: 0.728533. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Comment: @Anton how exactly did you do it with ChebyshevT? Thanks

Comment: @floyd17 The software monad `QRMon` has functions for doing Quantile Regression and Least Squares Fit using a user provided basis of functions, with a default basis made with Chebyshev polynomials. See the section "Default basis to fit (using Chebyshev polynomials)" in this [`QRMon` document](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/).

Answer (score 2):

Does the function have to go through all of the points? If not, how about fitting instead of interpolating.

```
dados16 = {{10, 0.37}, {15, 0.47}, {20, 0.54}, {25, 0.61}, {30, 0.70}, {40, 0.80},{50, 0.90}, {60, 1.01}, {70, 1.10}, {80, 1.20}, {90, 1.31}, {100, 1.42}, {110, 1.53}};

fit = Fit[dados16, {1, x, x^(1/2)}, x]
```

> 0.104065 + 0.0701194 Sqrt[x] + 0.00609645 x

```
Plot[fit, {x, 0, 110}, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, PointSize[.02], Point[dados16]}}]
```

[image]